# TextBox - прокрутка мышкой

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите, как сделать в textBox прокрутку текста колёсиком мыши ?

Comment: Берете колесо мыши и крутите. Какой вопрос, такой ответ. Что за TextBox? Winforms? WPF? Xamarin? WinSDK? Web? Догадаться надо?

Comment: @aepot, winforms. За место использования ScrollBars хочу прокручивать мышкой.

Comment: Так оно и так должно прокручиваться

Comment: @aepot, нет, оно не прокручивается. Если я убираю с текстбокса скроллинг, то текст не крутится по колёсику мышки. Вот я хочу узнать, есть ли какие-нибудь способы скроллинга по колёсику.

Comment: Так включите скроллбар и крутите мышкой. Одно без другого смысла не имеет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MouseScrollableTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case 0x020A: // WM_MOUSEWHEEL
                if (((int)m.WParam >> 16) > 0)
                    m.WParam = (IntPtr)0; // SB_LINEUP
                else
                    m.WParam = (IntPtr)1; // SB_LINEDOWN
                m.Msg = 277; // WM_VSCROLL;
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                break;

            default:
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```